# Until now + Past Perfect / Present Perfect

Tags: present-perfect

While watching a TV-series, I saw this first sentence. But ısn't it wrong? I think the second example is the right one.

> 1. Until now, all we ***have had*** in common was our bank.
> 2. Until now, all we ***had had*** in common was our bank".

Answer (score 1):

I think the present perfect is correct, in fact, the action took place in the past and continues until now. 
Instead,I would have used the past perfect with  " until then. Until then, all we had had in common was our bank .
Hope it helps ¡

Answer (score 0):

Present perfect is used for situations like this which include time up to (but not including) the present moment.

Thus, "Until now, all we have had ..." is a correct use of the present perfect.

Consider

> Until today the volcano has been dormant, but this morning it erupted.

"Today" is considered a "present time", so the present perfect can be used.

> Until 24 August 79AD the volcano had been dormant. But on that day it erupted and destroyed Pompeii.

The date refers to a specific time in the past, so the past perfect must be used.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across some examples where past perfect is used in combination with until now:

Until now experts had thought that antibodies could only tackle infections by attacking viruses outside cells, but work done by the MRC shows...

The West Country had until now only been considered a "low risk", but the attempt by Nicky Reilly has stunned counter-intelligence officers.